# Is RF propagation path loss symmetrical and independent of clutter location?

Tags: rf, propagation, loss, scattering

Scenario: Consider two measurement points, point one is about 3m above ground level within a cluster of buildings (such as within an office park), and point two is about 1km away with an elevation angle of 30 degrees from the first point.

With ideal isotropic transmit and receive antenna at both points, would the RF path loss measured at point one to point two be the same as the reverse (point two to point one)? Would the scattering and refraction much closer in proximity to point one make a difference measuring to and from it, in the 2.4GHz range for example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the channel you're considering is reciprocal. It doesn't matter which way around you're going through it.

BUT: For statistic properties, it *does* matter, and that's something you'll see when, for example, doing longer-term channel diversity measurements. That's a larger topic pretty quickly, so if MIMO / diversity gains is of no concern to you, let's not dig into that.